# Bootstrap form + jQuery validation - Small issue with validation display

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and i created a form according to their specs , then i used a predefined jquery form validation (/)

I'm having a small issue however , the "valid" button is showing beneath my input and increasing the length of my login-icon .

Is there any way to make the valid button  - next to the input instead ?

Before :

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [1.ii.gl](http://1.ii.gl/1QL1eZ.png))</sub>

After:

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [3.ii.gl](http://3.ii.gl/ZVCr_H.png))</sub>

My code for the first name input :

```
<div class="form-group">

                <label for="inputName">First Name</label>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <div class="input-group">

                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php fname_value() ?>">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Are you calling the validate function with any parameters?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){


  $('#login-form').validate({
     rules: {
  
      loginuser: {
         minlength: 5,
   maxlength:20,
         required: true,
       },
    loginpass: {
   required: true,
   minlength: 6,
   maxlength:20,
   wordonly: true
    },
    
    agree: "required"
    
     },
   highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
   }
   });

});